# plotting hurdle regression output

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am attempting to plot hurdle regression output with an interaction term in R, but I have some trouble doing so with the count portion of the model.

```
Model <- hurdle(Suicide. ~ Age + gender + bullying*support, dist = "negbin", link = "logit")
```

Since I am unaware of any packages that would allow me to plot the hurdle model in its entirety, I estimated each component separately (binomial logit and negative binomial count), using the `MASS` package, and I am attempting to plot the results.

So far, I have had the best luck using the `visreg` package for plotting, but I would like to hear other suggestions. I have been able to reproduce and successfully plot the original logistic output from the hurdle model in `MASS`, but not the negative binomial count data (i.e., the parameter estimates from `MASS` are not the same as they are in the hurdle regression output).

I would greatly appreciate any insight regarding how others have plotted hurdle regression results in the past, or how I might be able to reproduce negative binomial coefficients originally obtained from the hurdle model using `glm.nb()` in `MASS`.

Here is what I am using to plot my data:

```
##Logistic 

logistic<-glm(SuicideBinary ~ Age + gender + bullying*support, data = sx, family="binomial")

data("sx", package = "MASS")
##Linear scale
visreg(logistic, "bullying", by="support", xlab = "bullying", ylab = "Log odds (Suicide yes/no)")

##Logistic/probability scale
visreg(logistic, "bullying", by="support", scale = "response", xlab = "bullying", ylab = "P(Initial Attempt)")

##Count model

NegBin<-glm.nb(Suicide. ~ Age + gender + bullying*support, data = sx)

data("sx", package = "MASS")
##Linear scale
visreg(NegBin, "bullying", by="support", xlab = "bullying", ylab = "Count model (number of suicide attempts)")

##Logistic/probability scale
visreg(NegBin, "bullying", by="support", scale = "response", xlab = "bullying", ylab = "P(Subsequent Attempts)")
```

Comment: Models cannot be plotted; when you `plot(lm)` you are actually plotting residuals against fitted values, etc. What are you trying to plot? It would be easier to help if you presented a MWE, including data (`sx` isn't in my `MASS` package) and what you would change about the commands you're already running.

Comment: I'm trying to plot the data from the negative binomial count portion of my hurdle regression (I can plot the logistic portion just fine). I would be happy to provide data, if helpful. How should I go about doing this? And what do you mean by "MWE"? Hopefully these questions aren't painfully basic. :)

Comment: MWE = minimal working example

Comment: If you are asking about coding, then your question is off topic here. But it seems to me you may be asking about the plot itself, rather than how to implement it in R.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs clarification and is 4 years old.